# Critical exponent

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $1\leq p\leq \infty$. I want to show that there is at most $1\leq q \leq \infty$ such that there is $C>0$ with

$$||u||_q \leq C ||\nabla u ||_p \hspace{1cm} \forall u \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$$

This $q$ is somehow supposed to depend on $p$ and $d$. I don't know where to start - I've got the hint to look at $u \mapsto u_\lambda$ where $u_\lambda(x)=u(\lambda x)$ But that doesn't really help me.

Thank you

Comment: How is $\lVert u_{\lambda}\rVert_p$ related to $\lVert u\rVert_p$? How is $\lVert \nabla u_{\lambda}\rVert_q$ related to $\lVert \nabla u\rVert_q$? [Aside: you didn't use $q$ in the question, I guessed one of two possible places for it.]

Comment: I think it should be $||u_\lambda||_q=|\lambda|^{d/q}||u||_q$ and $||\nabla u_\lambda||_p=|\lambda|^{(d+1)/p}||\nabla u||_p$?

Comment: The exponents aren't correct, the factors should be $\lvert\lambda\rvert^{-d/q}$ and $\lvert\lambda\rvert^{(p-d)/p}$. But that doesn't change the principle. You want the same $C$ working for all $u\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$. What constraints on $p$ and $q$ do you get from plugging in $u_{\lambda}$?